# Grayed out settings in Home app for HomePod

Tags: homekit

Not sure if this is ios 15 thing. A lot of setting for my Homepod inside the Home app are grayed out, including 'Personal requests'. I can't change them. What's causing that? How do I change them?

Comment: Please add iOS and HomePod versions so users have more to work with.

Comment: Does the HomePod inside Home app say **Nor Responding** or **Updating**? This sounds more like your internet (wi-fi) connection issue to me.